# Date Formatting Consistency Across Time Zones

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, date

I'm currently working on a JavaScript function that formats dates using the `Intl.DateTimeFormat` constructor. The function takes a `date` string as input and formats it to a specific time zone using the timeZone option.

Here's a simplified version of the function:

```
const getFormattedDateString = (date) => {
    return new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', { dateStyle: 'full', timeStyle: 'full', timeZone: 'Africa/Casablanca' }).format(new Date(date));
};
```

As you can see I use the constructor `new Date(date)` before passing it to the `format` function. My understanding is that if the input date parameter is in UTC (e.g., '2023-06-19T18:24:41Z'), the formatted date string should remain consistent across different local time zones (where ever the user is in the world). However, if the input date parameter is not in UTC (e,g., '2023-06-19'), then formatting it to a different time zone will result in different formatted date strings depending on the where in the world the function is executed.

**Here are my two questions :**

1. So if I want the result of the function to be the same anywhere in the world (for a specific UTC date) I should make sure the `date` parameter is in UTC. Can anyone confirm this ?
2. I don't understand something. I saw that when I do this  :

   ```
   console.log(new Date("2023-06-19T18:24:41Z"))
   ```

   It gives me an date object in my timezone. So why does using it in the function above makes the date object consistent regardless of the local of the user running the code. There's a difference from what I log in the console vs the date object ?

Comment: `2023-06-19T18:24:41Z` mind the Z at the end, it signifies the zulu timezone. So this string includes information on which timezone it is in. So in the code above you are formatting date from one timezone to another, this is independent of user timezone as it should. To be honest, Date object in general is independant of the timezone, it's just the string representation that can show differences, but under the hood it all uses the same value.

Comment: "*I saw `new Date("2023-06-19T18:24:41Z")` […] gives me an date object in my timezone*" - no. It gives you a `Date` object, which just represents a specific instant, like a UTC timestamp. It's only `date.toString()` (which the console also uses) that formats this according to your system timezone.

Answer (score 2):

1. The parsing done by the `Date` object is [fully specified](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/numbers-and-dates.html#sec-date-time-string-format), so you can rely on it for strings in the format it defines (now; that wasn't always true). If the string has a timezone indicator on it (like `Z` for UTC), then the string defines a datetime in that timezone. The tricky bit is that if you *don't* have a timezone indicator in the string, the default is local time if the string has a time (`2024-02-09T08:23`) but UTC if it doesn't (`2024-02-09`).
2. A `Date` object is just a set of methods wrapped around a number of milliseconds since The Epoch (`1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`). Some of those methods (e.g. `getHours`) use the local timezone of the environment the code is running in. Others (e.g. `getUTCHours`) use UTC. `Date` objects have no concept of timezones *other* than UTC and the local timezone of the environment where the code is running. With your `console.log`, you're apparently seeing the result of formatting the date in local time (it varies depending on the console implementation).

   In contrast, with your `Intl.DateTimeFormat` code, you're *telling* it what timezone to use (`timeZone: 'Africa/Casablanca'`), so of course the resulting string uses that timezone.

Answer (score 1):

> So if I want the result of the function to be the same anywhere in the world (for a specific UTC date) I should make sure the date parameter is in UTC.

If the timestamp is in one of the [formats supported by ECMAScript](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-date.parse) and includes an offset, then all parsers should parse it to exactly the same [time value](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-time-values-and-time-range) (millisecond offset from the ECMAScript epoch). It doesn't need to be UTC.

In regard to supported formats:

1. *toString* includes the offset and timezone name, however the timezone name is irrelevant to parsing, only the offset is used
2. *toUTCString* is GMT (effectively UTC, zero offset)
3. *toISOString* is UTC (zero offset), however any timestamp consistent with that specified in [§21.4.1.18 Date Time String Format](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-date-time-string-format) is suitable and may have an offset other than zero

If the format of *toString* is used, any valid offset (including non–zero values) will produce consistent results. E.g.

```
Date.parse('Fri Feb 09 2024 21:26:12 GMT+1000 (Chamorro Standard Time)');
```

Similarly with timestamps consistent with the *Date Time String Format*:

```
Date.parse('2024-02-09T21:26:12+10:00')
```

Both the above produce the time value `1707477972000` regardless of the host timezone or offset settings. For the *toString* format, deleting the timezone name (or changing it to a nonsensical value) has no effect. Deleting the offset makes it inconsistent with ECMA-262 so parsing is implementation dependent (i.e. unreliable).

For the *Date Time String Format*, if the offset is removed, timestamps are parsed as local.

> I saw that when I do this :
>
> ```
> console.log(new Date("2023-06-19T18:24:41Z"))
> ```
>
> It gives me an date object in my timezone. So why does using it in the
> function above makes the date object consistent regardless of the
> local of the user running the code. There's a difference from what I
> log in the console vs the date object ?

The timestamp is one of the supported formats so all parsers should parse it to exactly the same time value (1687199081000). The trailing "Z" indicates zero offset (UTC) and is the same as "GMT+00:00".

As T.J. Crowder explained, it's an ECMAScript quirk (some might say bug) that timestamps of the format YYYY-MM-DD are parsed as UTC, but any other timestamp without an offset is parsed as local to the host doing the parsing.

PS
A pedant would say that UTC is a time standard, not a timezone. ;-)

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. To confirm, if the date string includes the UTC offset (e.g., "Z" for UTC), the function's result will be consistent regardless of the user's location, as all dates are stored in UTC. Similarly, dates in the format "YYYY-MM-DD" remain consistent due to this quirk. However, if the input lacks a timezone, it's interpreted in the user's local time and stored as a date object converted to UTC, leading to potential variations in the function's output. Right ?

Comment: @Nerd_Gotti— yes.